# Respond.js and Modernizr not working on IE8 for media queries

Tags: jquery, modernizr, polyfills

I have a blog I am trying to get to work across all browsers using bootstrap as a backbone for the project.  I am using Modernizr and Respond to force IE to respond to media queries, but for some reason the scripts aren't working. Am I placing them in an incorrect order or is another JS script overriding them? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/modernizr.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/scottjehl/Respond/master/respond.min.js"></script>          
    <!-- HTML Shim - Enables usage of all HTML5 elements in Internet Explorer -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>

    <!-- Selectivizr - Enable CSS3 selectors for IE 6-8 -->
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/libs/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/site.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
    <!-- wordpress head functions -->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
</head>
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever resolve this? It seems like a few of the answers below - combined - are an answer. Can you tell us how it went so we can learn from your experience? As far as I can tell, there are 3 issues. 1.) source order.  2.) adding "screen only and" to the @media rule, - and 3.) possible problems with nesting and SASS. Any insight would be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Try moving

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/scottjehl/Respond/master/respond.min.js"></script>
```

To go after your last stylesheet link (you might have missed it but there's one at the bottom).

Answer (score 3):

Just adding respond.js does not fix the media queries.  I used css3-mediaqueries.js and wrote my media queries like this:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      // css;
    }
```

instead of:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      // css;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. I found out it's my loading sequence problem, because I write CSS inline first so it looks like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />`

It should be

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>`

ALWAYS call stylesheets before scripts!